# "unknown sort" error in fixed point queries

Tags: z3, z3-fixedpoint

I am getting the "unknown sort" error when trying to pose a fixed point query using the `query` keyword.  For example, the following example from the fixed point tutorial, which works fine in the online version of Z3,

```
(declare-rel mc (Int Int))
(declare-var n Int)
(declare-var m Int)
(declare-var p Int)

(rule (=> (> m 100) (mc m (- m 10))))
(rule (=> (and (<= m 100) (mc (+ m 11) p) (mc p n)) (mc m n)))

(query (and (mc m n) (< n 91))
 :print-certificate true)
```

returns:

```
(error "line 9 column 13: unknown sort 'mc'")
```

when I run it from the command line.  I use Z3 version 4.4.2 compiled from the github repository on Linux. My command line is: `z3 -smt2 example.smt`

Are there some compilation flags I need to set to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently changed the format of "query" to use a predicate only.
The tutorial will have to be updated.

```
 (declare-rel q (Int Int))
 (rule (=> (and (mc m n) (< n 91)) (q m n)))
 (query q :print-certificate true)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, it solved the problem! I am now running into a memory corruption issue, which causes a crash for any fixpoint query on my x86_64 Linux machine, which I submitted as [Issue #420](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/420) on the github bug tracker.